# Multiple z-index elements

Tags: css, html

I' am doing a project and I have a little issue with z-index property.

Here is my code:

(HTML)

```
 <div class="outer_obw">
  <div class="obw1">
    <div class="box" id="blue_box">
      <div id="inn_blue" class="inner_box"><p>Box1</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main_box_content">
    <div class="back_box">
      <div class="main_box"> 

        <p id="texts">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="obw3">
        <div class="box" id="green_box">
          <div id="inn_green" class="inner_box"><p>Box2</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(CSS)

```
.outer_obw {
   width: 78.5%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
.obw1 {    
   min-height: 80px;
}
.obw3 {
   min-height: 80px;
   margin-top: -40px;
}
.box {
   width: 25.25%;
   min-height: 80px;
   cursor:pointer;  
   position: relative;
}
.inner_box {
   height: 68px;
   margin: -10.5px 6px;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative; 
}
#inn_blue {
   background-color: #fff;
   z-index: 5;
}
#inn_green {
   background-color: #fff;
   z-index: 5;
}
#blue_box {
   background-color: blue;
   float: left; 
   z-index: 1;
}
#green_box {
   background-color: green;
   float: right;
}
.main_box_content {
   display: table;
   width: 78.5%;
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: -40px;
}
.back_box {
   display: table;
   background-color: blue;
   width: 65%;
   margin: 0 17%;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 3;
}
.main_box {
   display: table;
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
   margin: 6px;
   padding: 0.5% 3%;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 10;
}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/vuluziyido/1/edit?html,css,output) is all code and visualization.

I intended to achieve such an effect:

[image]

All what I need to do is insert inn_blue and inn_green (white fields of box1 and box2) between main_box (gray field with a text) and back_box (red background of the main box.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Z-index of the main_box should be greater than z-index of inn_blue/inn_green and z-index of the inn_blue/inn_green should be greater then  back_box.

And so it is in my code, but the effect is not what I expected...

So the question is what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are so many layers of complexity in your example. Instead, let's use the natural layers to our advantage and position with `absolute` and minimal markup.

### The basics

Start off with a wrapper to contain your three boxes:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

The wrapper will be `position: relative` and its three children will be positioned with `position: absolute` and `top` / `right` / `bottom` / `left`. In order to allow a flexible size that resizes in proportion, we can make use of the [viewport width (`vw`) unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) for both the width *and* the height. Each child div is given a percentage height.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: #EEE;
  height: 60vw;
  width: 80vw;
}
.wrapper div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 25%;
  width: 20%;
}
.wrapper .one {
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
  background: blue;
}
.wrapper .two {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -23% 0 0 -31%;
  height: 60%;
  width: 62%;
  background: red;
}
.wrapper .three {
  bottom: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

That gives us this:

[image: Example 1]

#### Layer the main box

Now we want the red square to overlap both the blue and green squares. All we have to do is move the red `<div>` below them in the markup. The last element in the markup will overlap the elements before it naturally.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
  <div class="two"></div><!-- move it one line down -->
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: #EEE;
  height: 60vw;
  width: 80vw;
}
.wrapper div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 25%;
  width: 20%;
}
.wrapper .one {
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
  background: blue;
}
.wrapper .two {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -23% 0 0 -31%;
  height: 60%;
  width: 62%;
  background: red;
}
.wrapper .three {
  bottom: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
  <div class="two"></div><!-- move it one line down -->
</div>
```

Now we have the correct layers:

[image: Example 2]

### Add the border layers

In order to reduce complexity, we can create the box borders with [`:before` pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before). These will create the extra elements we need to create the overlapping borders.

Give each child div a `:before` element and background color like below:

```
.wrapper div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.one:before {
  background: blue;
}
.two:before {
  background: red;
}
.three:before {
  background: green;
}
```

The `-1` z-index will ensure that they are overlapped by the div backgrounds and the `-6px` position on all sides pulls them outside by 6px to give us a 6px border.

### The final product

We add `z-index: 1` to the wrapper, so that it wont overlap our border pseudo elements. `box-sizing: border-box` is used so that the padding is incorporated into the widths and heights.

#### Example 1

**Limitation of this example:** We cannot use `overflow` to hide excessive text on the main box, as it will cut off our border or cause a scroll bar to always be present..

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: #EEE;
  height: 60vw;
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: 772px;
  max-height: 579px;
  min-width: 390px;
  min-height: 292px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper div {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #FFF;
  height: 25%;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.wrapper div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.one:before {
  background: blue;
}
.two:before {
  background: red;
}
.three:before {
  background: green;
}
.wrapper .one {
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
}
.wrapper .two {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -23% 0 0 -31%;
  height: 60%;
  width: 62%;
  background: #EEE;
  text-align: left;
}
.wrapper .three {
  bottom: 16px;
  right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">Box1</div>
  <div class="three">Box3</div>
  <div class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
```

#### Example 2

Slightly less elegant, the main box border is positioned relative to the wrapper itself, we *can* use `overflow` in this example to cut off or scroll excessive text.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: #EEE;
  height: 60vw;
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: 772px;
  max-height: 579px;
  min-width: 390px;
  min-height: 292px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper div {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #FFF;
  height: 25%;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  margin: -23% 0 0 -31%;
  top: calc(50% - 6px);
  left: calc(50% - 6px);
  height: calc(60% + 12px);
  width: calc(62% + 12px);
  background: #F00;
  z-index: -1;
}
.wrapper div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.one:before {
  background: blue;
}
.three:before {
  background: green;
}
.wrapper .one {
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
}
.wrapper .two {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -23% 0 0 -31%;
  height: 60%;
  width: 62%;
  background: #EEE;
  text-align: left;
}
.wrapper .three {
  bottom: 16px;
  right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">Box1</div>
  <div class="three">Box3</div>
  <div class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

By streamlining the markup and css a bit and only z-indexing the necessaries (namely .top-box-border and .mid-box-inner) I believe I have what you're looking for:

```css
[class*="border"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid green;
  position: relative;
}
[class*="inner"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #999;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1ex 1em;
}
.mid-box-border {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-color: blue;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: 75px;
}
.mid-box-inner {
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 20;
}
.bot-box-border {
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: 255px;
}
.top-box-border {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-box-border">
  <div class="top-box-inner">Box 1</div>
</div>
<div class="mid-box-border">
  <div class="mid-box-inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic accusantium dicta sint a cum eveniet, id! Corrupti sit reprehenderit ad veniam ratione mollitia molestiae, sapiente quasi id esse, incidunt eligendi.</div>
</div>
<div class="bot-box-border">
  <div class="bot-box-inner">Box 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `position: initial;` for `.back_box`

Answer (score 1):

Just make position relative for each box and position absolute for the background(border) and content holder to make them out of their workflow, then first element will take higher `z-index` and the elements in the back will take lower, look at this one https://jsfiddle.net/s3y94x1w/

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.cont {
    width: 100%;
}

.blue-box {
    width: 20%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 8%;
    cursor: pointer
}

.blue-box .background {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    
}

.blue-box .content {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 2
}

.red-box {
    width: 40%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 19%;
    margin-top: -70px;
}

.red-box .background {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.red-box .content {
    background-color: #eee;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
    overflow: hidden
}

.green-box {
    width: 20%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-top: -70px;
    cursor: pointer
}

.green-box .background {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1
}

.green-box .content {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="blue-box">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="content">Box1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="red-box">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="green-box">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="content">Box2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```